# CLIPS code no result

Tags: clips

I am new to CLIPS and I can't figure out why my code doesn't run. Actually I get no errros, but when I press run the facts don't change and the goal is never found. The project is that we have 2 bottles. Bottle A with capacity 3 and B with capacity 2. The goal is A has 0 and B has 1. We can do it with these rules: fillA,fillB,emptyA,emptyB,moveAB,moveBA.
Below is my code. Can someone help?thanks!

```
(deffacts problem
   (name A cap 3 water 0)
   (name B cap 2 water 0)
)

(defrule goal
 (declare (salience 100))
 (name A water 0)
 (name B water 1)
=>
 (printout t "FOUND" crlf)
 (halt)
)

(defrule start
 (initial-fact)
=>
 (set-strategy random)
)

(defrule emptyA
 ?x<-(name A water ?w)
=>
 (retract ?x)
 (assert (name A water 0))
)

(defrule emptyB
 ?x<-(name B water ?w)
=>
 (retract ?x)
 (assert (name B water 0))
)

(defrule fillA
 ?x<-(name A water ?w)
=>
 (retract ?x)
 (assert (name A water 3))
)

(defrule fillB
 ?x<-(name B water ?w)
=>
 (retract ?x)
 (assert (name B water 2))
)

(defrule moveAB
 ?x<-(name A water ?w)
 ?y<-(name B water ?water)
 (test (not (< ?w 0)))
 (test (not (> ?water 2)))
=>
 (retract ?x ?y)
 (assert (name B water ?w))
 (assert (name A water ?water))
)

(defrule moveBA
 ?x<-(name A water ?w)
 ?y<-(name B water ?water)
 (test (not (> ?w 3)))
 (test (not (< ?water 0)))
=>
 (retract ?x ?y)
 (assert (name A water ?water))
 (assert (name B water ?w))
)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to add the initial-fact to a rule with no other conditions; it is added automatically in versions of CLIPS prior to version 6.3. The initial-fact functionality was deprecated in the 6.3 release; it is still asserted by a reset, but rules without conditions no longer rely on it. In the 6.4 release, the initial-fact is no longer asserted, so rules that explicitly match this fact will no longer be activated.

Answer (score 1):

All of your fact patterns match name facts with three fields. Your name facts have five fields. There needs to be an exact match. For example, instead of the following pattern:

```
(name B water ?w)
```

You should use:

```
(name B cap ? water ?w)
```

or:

```
(name B cap ?c water ?w)
```

Alternately, use deftemplate facts so that you can specify only the slots of interest in your patterns:

```
(deftemplate bottle
   (slot name)
   (slot cap)
   (slot water (default 0)))

(deffacts problem
   (bottle (name A) (cap 3))
   (bottle (name B) (cap 2)))

(defrule fillA
   ?x <- (bottle (name A ) (water ?w))
   =>
   (modify ?x (water 3)))
```